# (# ﾟДﾟ) is a 5-letter-word. But in iOS, [@"(# ﾟДﾟ)" length] is 7. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uitextinput

(# ﾟДﾟ) is a 5-letter-word. But in iOS, [@"(# ﾟДﾟ)" length] is 7.

1. Why?
2. I'm using `<UITextInput>` to modify the text in a `UITextField` or `UITextView`. When I make a UITextRange of 5 character length, it can just cover the (# ﾟДﾟ) . So, why this (# ﾟДﾟ) looks like a 5-character-word in `UITextField` and `UITextView`, but looks like a 7-character-word in NSString???
3. How can I get the correct length of a string in this case?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say character encoding - does NSString count number of bytes vs number of characters? perhaps 2 of your characters are actually multi-byte characters, and NSString trips up... as stated, that is a guess

Comment: (# ﾟДﾟ) has 7 characters if you copy and paste it in a text editor.

Comment: It "looks like" a 6-character word to me because there is a space at the end.  However "Дﾟ" is actually two characters in unicode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** As many in the comments have already stated, Your string is made of 5 composed character sequences (or character clusters if you prefer). When broken down by `unichar`s as `NSString`’s `length` method does you will get a 7 which is the number of `unichar`s it takes to represent your string in memory.

**2)** Apparently the `UITextField` and `UITextView` are handling the strings in a unichar savvy way. Good news, so can you. See #3.

**3)** You can get the number of composed character sequences by using some of the `NSString` API which properly deals with composed character sequences. A quick example I baked up, very quickly, is a small `NSString` category:

```
@implementation NSString (ComposedCharacterSequences_helper)
-(NSUInteger)numberOfComposedCharacterSequences{
    __block NSUInteger count = 0;
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                          usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
                              NSLog(@"%@",substring); // Just for fun
                              count++;
                          }];
    return count;
}
@end
```

Again this is quick code; but it should get you started. And if you use it like so:

```
NSString *string = @"(# ﾟДﾟ)";
NSLog(@"string length %i", string.length);
NSLog(@"composed character count %i", [string numberOfComposedCharacterSequences]);
```

You will see that you get the desired result.

For an in-depth explanation of the `NSString` API check out the `WWDC 2012 Session 215 Video "Text and Linguistic Analysis"`

Answer (score 1):

Both `ﾟ` and `Дﾟ` are represented by a [character sequence](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr34/#Notation) of two Unicode characters (even when they are visually presented as one). `-[NSString length]` reports the number of Unicode chars:

> The number returned includes the individual characters of composed
>   character sequences, so **you cannot use this method to determine if a
>   string will be visible when printed or how long it will appear**.

If you want to see the byte representation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString* describeUnicodeCharacters(NSString* str)
{
    NSMutableString* codePoints = [NSMutableString string];
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; ++i){
        long ch = (long)[str characterAtIndex:i];
        [codePoints appendFormat:@"%0.4lX ", ch];
    }
    return codePoints;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *s = @" ﾟДﾟ";
        NSLog(@"%ld unicode chars. bytes: %@", 
            [s length], describeUnicodeCharacters(s));
    }
}
```

The output is: `4 unicode chars. bytes: 0020 FF9F 0414 FF9F`.

2) and 3): what NJones said.